# Use of unassigned local variable in my class(c#, silverlight)

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, silverlight-4.0

I know that there are many topics with this problem but I have not find my case.

I've got an error "Use of unassigned local variable 'flags'"

```
public class Flag : INotifyPropertyChanged
{

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged; 

    private string _Tag;
    public string Tag
    {
        get { return _Tag; }
        set
        {
            _Tag = value;
            NotifyPropertyChanged("Tag");
        }
    }

    private string _Name;
    public string Name
    {
        get { return _Name; }
        set
        {
            _Name = value;
            NotifyPropertyChanged("Name");
        }
    }

    private void NotifyPropertyChanged(string propertyName)
    {
        if (null != PropertyChanged)
            PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }

    const string filename = "Flags.xml";
    public void Save()
    {
        IsolatedStorageFile storage = IsolatedStorageFile.GetUserStoreForApplication();
        IsolatedStorageFileStream stream = storage.CreateFile(filename);
        XmlSerializer xml = new XmlSerializer(GetType());
        xml.Serialize(stream, this);
        stream.Close();
        stream.Dispose();
    }
}
```

problem in the main part of code when I try to assigned flags

```
   public partial class MainPage : PhoneApplicationPage
    {

        public MainPage()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            Flag flags;          
            flags.Name = "1111"; //I here error
            flags.Tag = "1";     //I
                                 //I
            flags.Save();        //I
        }
    }
```

Comment: Always mark the correct answer after getting problem solved.

Comment: thats true, none of your question has marked answer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to initialize `flags`:

```
public partial class MainPage : PhoneApplicationPage
{
    public MainPage()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        Flag flags = new Flag();          
        flags.Name = "1111"; 
        flags.Tag = "1";     
        flags.Save();        
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You need to instantiate this class variable.

When you wil instantiate it while declaring the class object `Flag flags=new Flag()` , this error will go.

Your whole function will look like:

```
 public MainPage()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        Flag flags = new Flag();          
        flags.Name = "1111"; 
        flags.Tag = "1";     
        flags.Save();        
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

Create an object of the Flag flags. then try to assign it.

```
Flag flags = new Flag();
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this

```
Flag flags = new Flag();
```

Answer (score 2):

As per your code flag is a class and you cannot initialize the values of the member variables of the class unless and until you have assigned some space for the object of the class on the memory heap. You can construct an object of a class using the new keyword as shown below.

```
Flag flags = new Flag();
```

Here flags is a variable of type Flag which again contains the reference to an object of type Flag.

Now since you have assigned some memory space to the flags variable which would again initialize the space for its member variable, the value to these momber variables you can assign using below code-

```
flags.Name = "1234"; 
flags.Tag = "12";
```

Mark this as answer if helped you in understanding the problem.